# trigger send thank you email when a new subscriber is added to the list -exacttarget

Tags: marketing-cloud

Landing page containing form ->customer submit --> new subscriber is created in list.

I want NOW to now send the triggered send thank you email confirmation to the newly added subscriber.

The landing page processing form contains API AMPscript ...

any pointers?

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a checkbox field on the subscriber record
2. Create a workflow rule to fire on insert and every time updated and checkbox field in #1 is FALSE
3. Add email alert to send email and field update to set the checkbox field in #1 to true

This will send an email alert to the email address associated with the record (you define) and then check the checkbox so it does not get sent the next time the record is updated. You can force a resend by unchecking the checkbox as well.

Comment: Wonder if am unclear . Do we have workflow in Exacttarget? it looks a nice solution but i dont seems to find workflows in exacttarget account.

Answer (score 2):

If you use ET's [Web Collect](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/web_collect/) on your landing page, just configure your List to use a [Welcome email](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/welcome_email/).   If your landing page is using the API, then you'll need to trigger a [Triggered Send Definition](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/triggered_emails/triggered_emails_guide/how_to_create_a_triggered_email_message_interaction/) via [API](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/triggered_email_scenario_guide_for_developers/).

Comment: Unfortunately, Webcollect is not enabled to the account.LP form uses API AMPscript and wonder if could use triggered send in the UI plus triggering the send with the API AMPscript or SSJS..

Comment: There's no reason why you can't trigger an email via AMPScript.  [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15886835) an example.

Answer (score 1):

When you create the user in the list, you should get back a success/failure response. Check the status if success then send TriggeredSend. To eliminate duplicate sends you could create a tracking DE and store that email address in the DE, then check if the email address exists in the DE before triggering the send.

1. Create user in list
2. Check create status (success/error)
3. If success check if user exists in tracking DE else if error show error message
4. If user does not exist in tracking DE send trigger else do nothing

Comment: I will give a try ..